# $this->load->model() not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

I'm using CodeIgniter 2.1.2 and here's my situation right now. I have a model named math.php in `C:\wamp\www\cr8v\application\models`. I am trying to load this in my controller from `C:\wamp\www\cr8v\application\controllers\site.php` yet I am getting this error:

> Unable to locate the model you have specified: math_model

Here's the content of `math.php`:

```
 <?php
    class Math_model extends CI_Model(){
        public function add(){
            return 1+1;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

And here's the content of my `site.php`:

```
<?php
    class Site extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){
            $this->addstuff();
        }

        public function addstuff(){
            $this->load->model("math_model");
            echo $this->math->add();
        }
    }  
?>
```

I followed this in a tutorial in YouTube. Yet, it doesn't give me my desired output. I've tried Googling about it and read other related questions with this, however those information are not enough.

I have read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8074368) just a while ago.

Now I have the following error:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' in C:\wamp\www\cr8v\application\models\math_model.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0036  148768  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0062  185072  require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\cr8v\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' )  ..\index.php:202
3   0.0561  784312  call_user_func_array ( )    ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
4   0.0561  784360  Site->index( )  ..\CodeIgniter.php:359
5   0.0561  784376  Site->addstuff( )   ..\site.php:4
6   0.0561  784504  CI_Loader->model( ) ..\site.php:8
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name needs to be the same in all places:

Here:

```
class Math_model extends CI_Model {
   // your model
}
```

Here:

```
$this->load->model("math_model");
```

When using it:

```
$this->math_model->add();
```

And: in your file system. So rename `math.php` to `math_model.php` and it will work.

Comment: uh i have done what you have said however i got the same error as per the part where i edited my question.. The parse error and so on and so forth

Answer (score 3):

The name of the file should be math_model.php and you should call it like this:

```
echo $this->math_model->add();
```

Comment: uh i have done what you have said however i got the same error as per the part where i edited my question.. The parse error and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

File name and model name should be same
try this instead

```
class Math_model extends CI_Model {
   // your code
}
```

and the file name 
should be Math_model.php

Comment: This was my issue, specifically I used _Model instead of _model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered really and the problem was this:

```
 <?php
    class Math_model extends CI_Model(){
        //so on
        } 
 ?>
```

..it's the open and close parethesis after declaring the class..
it should be:

```
 <?php
    class Math_model extends CI_Model{
        //so on
        } 
 ?>
```

thank you so much for those who responded

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should always be noted that function name should not be replicated with controller or model name such as below;

```
<?php
  class Abc extends CI_Controller{

public function abc(){} // this confused CI in loading   

}
```

this may be helpful for developers new to CI,