# i hope i can solve here Undefined property: Siswa::$siswa_model

Tags: php, codeigniter

,Message: Call to a member function get_paged_list() on null  Filename: controllers/siswa.php
this my full code
http://pastebin.com/ZBHkBS8i

Problem solved,thanks to baci and bora

Comment: it would help if you put the model too

Comment: Try with lowercase model name on loading model like `$this->load->model('siswa_model')` instead of `$this->load->model('Siswa_model')`

Comment: still error Unable to locate the model you have specified: Siswa_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't call the model like this

```
$siswas = $this->siswa_model->
get_paged_list($this->limit,$offset,$order_column,$order_type) ->result();
```

but like this

```
$this->load->model("siswa_model");
$result = $this->siswa_model->
get_paged_list($this->limit,$offset,$order_column,$order_type)
```

and in the model you should query the database end return the result, something like this

```
public function get_paged_list($limit,$order_column,$order_type)
{
$q_str = "select * from table ....etc ";
$q = $this->db->query($q_str);
return $q->result();
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: sory baci yesterday i have holiday, i try your sugestion,but i find error like this

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: Siswa_model
whats wrong now?thanks before

Comment: now you must check your model if it is in the right place and with the right name  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074368/codeigniter-php-model-access-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified

Comment: thanks,the file name must same as my model,i now understood,thanks baci :-) ,
problem solved

Comment: sure, but i will add some question in next time :-)

Comment: this the error : Message: Call to a member function save() on null