# Unable to locate the model you have specified in CodeIgniter:

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to call a model in controller in codeigniter but that give me error that  to locate the model you have specified. Everything looks ok in my code but I did not get why it is not finding the model here is my model

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Register_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database("chandqki_mmusic");

    }

    public function insert_users_to_db($data)
    {

        return $this->db->insert('music_user_register', $data);

    }
}
?>
```

and in my controller I am calling this model

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

     public function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
     }

    public function index()

    {

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('Home_view');
        $this->load->model('register_model');

    }
}
```

From my side its code is looking ok but May be I am missing somewhere can anybody help me regarding this. I have go through all the answers of stackoverflow and check all the whatever they say everything is I am following like that but still I am unable to solve it

Thanks

Comment: What is your model file name ?

Comment: Register_model is my model name

Comment: register_model.php

Comment: check your model file name and class name are equal

Comment: I did not create controller constructer.. is it required??

Comment: try creating a new model, with no function. and try calling it in model

Comment: yes and call parent constructer

Comment: I added controller constructer but still not working and also update my controller code in question @BikashP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model file name must be ucfirst

```
Register_model.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$this->load->model('register_model');
```

with

```
$this->load->model('Register_model');
```

R in register in caps.

Comment: Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Register_model

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074368/codeigniter-php-model-access-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified

Comment: I already try this infact I try every example of stackoverflow but nothing work for me