# How to change base_url() path from localhost to hosted site?

Tags: codeigniter, web-hosting

I have hosted CodeIgniter project in hostgator. In localhost project was working fine and I took that project and hosted in my domain and there I have set
base_url like this:

```php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.com/';
```

But it is not working in server.

Comment: set base_url() in config file along with your application folder name

Comment: show the code where you load your model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to your config.php file and set your base_url there and make sure your model first letter is capitalized and dont forget to autoload your model or manually load it. if still not working try the link below

try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074368/codeigniter-php-model-access-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified) and see if this would help you.