# unable to locate the model you have specified errror

Tags: codeigniter

When I upload my website on the server I m getting this error

> unable to locate the model you have specified

but in localhost, it is working fine

Comment: it should be showing you other details as well, or is this all the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter PHP Model Access "Unable to locate the model you have specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074368/codeigniter-php-model-access-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified)

Answer (score 0):

Please state the error which you are facing with more details

Although check the following points

1. check whether you have loaded the model in controller. It is most preferable that you load model in your constructor

   $this->load->model('Example_model');
2. if you have model in a specific folder then the path will be as following

   $this->load->model('folder_name/Example_model');
3. Check the name on model class. The first letter should be capital

   class Example_model extends CI_Model{
       }