# Codeignitor - An uncaught Exception was encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to fetch users by creating model and controller, I am just at initial stage of learning codeignitor, can anyone help?

controllers/Users.php:

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller {
    
    public function show(){
        
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $result = $this->user_model->get_users();
        foreach($result as $object){
            echo $object->id;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

models/user_model.php:

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function get_users(){
    $this->db->get('users');
    }
}

?>
```

Error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: User_model

Filename: /home/sanadpjz/public_html/ci/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 314

Backtrace:

File: /home/sanadpjz/public_html/ci/application/controllers/Users.php
Line: 7
Function: model

File: /home/sanadpjz/public_html/ci/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

URL vising:

```
example.com/ci/index.php/users/show
```

Database configured in config/config.php
Database table 'users' exists and has 1 record.

Comment: are you using codeigniter 4 or 3 or 2 ?

Comment: You need to specify your model's namespaces

Comment: @NaveedRamzan CodeIgniter Version 3.0.1

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand can you help to do that, I am beginner.

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077427/15043040

Comment: it's `user_model.php`
And I also tried with `User_model.php` but getting same error.

Comment: First check user_model.php in models folder, on linux User_model.php and user_model.php are 2 different files Keep your model and controller file names Users.php and User_model.php

Answer (score 0):

It is clear the loader is unable to find the model file and that is because you are naming the file wrongly. The file name should start with a capital letter as the class name, mentioned in [CI3 documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html).

To fix your issue change your model file from

> models/user_model.php

to

> models/User_model.php.